# Control numérico en consola

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber como colocar un control para que el número ingresado esté entre 0 y 48 y no se puedan colocar letras, este es el código que tengo:

```
class Program
{
    static void agregar(int[] lista, int cantidad, ref int tope)
    {//agrega un nuevo elemento a un array con tope
        lista[tope] = cantidad;
        tope++;
    }


    static void cargarjugada (int[,]m, int napostante) //CARGAR LA JUGADA PARA CADA APOSTANTE
    {
        for(int col=0; col<m.GetLength(1);col++)
        {

                m[napostante,col] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] nombre;
        string[] apellido;
        int opcion, tope = 0, cantidad;
        bool seguir = true;



        Console.WriteLine("\t\t*****Bienvenidos al 5 de Oro*****");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la cantidad de apostantes: ");
        cantidad= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] vector = new int[cantidad];
        nombre = new string[cantidad];
        apellido = new string[cantidad];
        int[,] matriz = new int[cantidad, 5];


        while (seguir)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t1-Agregar apuesta");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t2-Agregar apuesta sorpresa");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t3-Eliminar Apuesta");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t    4-Ver numeros Cliente");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t    5-Ver listado de apuestas");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t    6-Ver numeros sin aciertos");
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t7-Salir");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Ingrese opcion: ");
            opcion = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (opcion)
            {

                case 1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t1 - Agregue una apuesta: ");
                    if (tope < nombre.Length)
                    {

                        Console.Write("Ingrese Nombre: ");
                        nombre[tope] = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim();
                        Console.Write("Ingrese Apellido: ");
                        apellido[tope] = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim();
                        Console.Write("Ingrese su Jugada : ");

                        cargarjugada(matriz, tope);
                        agregar(vector, cantidad, ref tope);


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No hay mas cupos");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, podrías aplicar también Programación Orientada a Objetos. Declaras una clase Apuesta con a priori como propiedades `Nombre`, `Apellido`,  `Jugada`( esta última analizar si debe ser otra clase. Luego cuando pidas los datos, en los métodos set {} de la propiedad puedes realizar la validación requerida (a parte de establecer como tipo un  `ìnt` y así evitar que introduzcan datos no válidos....

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el método

```
int.TryParse(string, out int)
```

En la string pones la string a convertir y en int la variable int donde se guardará el dato en formato integer si es un número.

Este método devuelve un boolean por tanto podrías hacer

```
if(int.TryParse("33", out miInteger))
{
  //es un numero además queda guardado en miInteger
}
else
{
    //no es un número y en miInteger se queda su valor anterior
}
```

Luego dentro de if comprobarías si está entre 0 y 48 que eso con un if es sencillo.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Intenta algo como esto:

```
try{
    cantidad=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }catch(Exeption e){
      cantidad=-500;
    }
    if(cantidad>0&&cantidad<49){
    //lo que harás después
    }
    else{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingresaste una cantidad inválida");
    }
```

El `try` está intentando convertir a int lo que recupera desde `Console.WriteLine();`, en caso contrario, "atrapa" el error, y no hace nada con la variable, podrías asignarle a propósito un valor erróneo, como hice yo en el ejemplo.
Después con un if compruebas que esté entre el rango de numero que deseas, si es correcto, haz lo que sigue en tu código, caso contrario, puedes notificarle que esta mal el dato que ingresó, espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por el dato pero es para el método del case 1 cuando pide que ingrese los números, no la cantidad de apostantes, espero tu respuesta, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: estoy entendiendo que quieres algún tipo de control, para que después de X cantidad de veces que se use el método, salga de él? si ese es el caso, necesitas agregar un for que realize dicho método las veces que necesites. Confirmame que estoy en lo correcto para que edite la pregunta @Cheska

Comment: Nunca se debe controlar el flujo del programa mediante `try/catch`. Para hacer lo mismo que en tu respuesta existe el método `TryParse`.